# Angularjs page not loadingon IE11 with routing and JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, url-routing

I have an issue with Angular and internet Explorer (it's working on chrome and Safari)
I am making a blog with different article from json data, and when you click on the article, a new page is loading with the details of the article from a single json data.
I have followed the Angular tuotial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Code of the blog page:

```
 <li ng-repeat="article in articles.articles">        {{article.titre}}
                <a href="blog/{{article.id}}"> go </a>
 </li>
```

Code of
 `<div ng-bind-html="articleBlog"></div>`

And the javascript (controller):

```
monitorControllers.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$sce',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce) {

        $http.get('data/'+$routeParams.articleId+'.json').success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.articleBlog= data.texte;
        })
    }]);
```

And the routing

```
.when('/blog/:articleId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/article.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
```

Comment: And what exactly isn't working? Are you getting errors? Does your data get logged to the console correctly? Also you should use `ng-href` instead of just `href` in your anchor tag [ng-href reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Comment: please elaborate on what is not working... create a jsFiddle or a plunker.

Comment: Yes I tried ng-href but it doesn't work. And there is no errors in the IE console. You can see directly the example on the website http://webtoutsaint.com/blog . Click on "Article" and it should work with chrome but not ie